# HashMap throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, java-8

If i'm getting the following error

```
    Map<String, Object> foodData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    foodData.put("penguin", 1);
    foodData.put("flamingo", 2);
    Map<String,Object> synchronizedFoodData = Collections.synchronizedMap(foodData);
    for(String key: synchronizedFoodData.keySet())
    synchronizedFoodData.remove(key);
```

**Question** :- **Why** This code throws a **`ConcurrentModificationException`** at runtime, whereas the same code with `ConcurrentHashMap` did not :-

```
    Map<String, Object> foodData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
    foodData.put("penguin", 1);
    foodData.put("flamingo", 2);
    Map<String,Object> synchronizedFoodData = Collections.synchronizedMap(foodData);
    for(String key: synchronizedFoodData.keySet())
    synchronizedFoodData.remove(key);
```

Why it is not showing any error.
**Im expecting internal working with some clear example** :-

Means i'm still using the **Collections.synchronizedMap(foodData);** still getting error which should not be case.

1. What is the wrong with my first code ?
2. Then Both HashMap and Collections.synchronizedMap is throwing error so when to use that synchronizedMap  ?

Comment: From ConcurrentHashMap's documentation: "They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException"

Comment: maybe because `ConcurrentHashMap` is for `synchronizedMap`, see this link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda question is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Well showing **internal workings** is not going to be easy - especially in the case of `CHM` - it's by far not a trivial implementation. But if you really want to - you can look at the sources and ask *specific* questions.

So, you are expecting that a synchronized `Map` to act as the `CHM` *without* throwing exceptions on removal *while* traversing? That is not the case, synchronized has nothing to do with that and the documentation specially does not say anything about it. All that is guaranteed via `Collections.synchronizedMap` is that each method is protected by a shared mutex, thus a single thread can access a single method: nothing more, nothing less.

The internal details of `CHM` are completely different - and the documentation specifically says - `Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration.  They do **not** throw java.util.ConcurrentModificationException ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: Why the first code which uses the HashMap throwing exception ?

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra because that's how the implementation works... I don't quite get your question to be honest. It's like asking why `ArrayList` expands it's internal array... it's just the way it was coded.

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra do you mean that even if you synchronize access to it, it's still throwing an Exception? well synchronized has nothing to do with why it should or not throw that Exception on removal

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra `synchronizedMap` will prevent multiple accesses to the `Map` from multiple threads, but it will still leave the fail-fast iterator - the *only* thing that it does - it wraps the methods of a plain `HashMap` to be protected via a `mutex`.

Comment: The Method in Synchorizzed HashMap:-

 `public V get(Object key) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.get(key);}
        }

        public V put(K key, V value) {
            synchronized (mutex) {return m.put(key, value);}
        }
`
**ConcurrentHashMap same as HashMap**
 `final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent)
{
 //No mutext code 
}
`
So based on that What is the actually differnce between ConcurrentHashMap and HashMap apart from providing fail-safe iteratorion

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra *lots* and stack overflow is probably **full** of these comparisons and differences. Really, honestly, there are *a lot* of discussions about it...

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation we learn that the iterators returned are fail-fast, meaning they'd rather fail when they sense something sketchy instead of keep going and eventually introducing errors.

The sketchy part in your code is how you remove the element. If the map is modified **after** the iterator was created it will throw this exception. You can avoid this by removing elements through the iterators **own** remove method.

What you want to do is to explicitly create the iterator and use that interface to remove items, rather than iterate over the Map object itself.

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because they are designed like this.

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. **They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html